# acp: missing destination file in target file generation for ota generation using make dist

Tags: android, build, raspberry-pi4, ninja, ota

**make -j8 dist DIST_DIR=dist_output**

When i execute the above command, I am getting the following error:

Environment variable DIST_DIR was modified (out/dist => dist_output), regenerating...
**[ 66% 10/15] Package target files: out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald.zip
FAILED: out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald.zip**
/bin/bash -c "(rm -rf out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald.zip out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4
-target_files-eng.jerald.zip.list out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald ) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_
intermediates/ out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald ) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_
rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/BOOT ) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/ROOT ) && (if [ -d "out/target/product/rpi4/root"
-a "$(ls -A  out/target/product/rpi4/root)" ]; then mkdir -p out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/ROOT && prebuilts/build-tools/linux
-x86/bin/acp -rd out/target/product/rpi4/root/* out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/ROOT; fi ) && (if [ -d "out/target/product/rpi4/ram
disk" -a "$(ls -A  out/target/product/rpi4/ramdisk)" ]; then mkdir -p out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/BOOT/RAMDISK && prebuilts/
build-tools/linux-x86/bin/acp -rd out/target/product/rpi4/ramdisk/* out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/BOOT/RAMDISK; fi ) && (cp out/ta
rget/product/rpi4/kernel out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/BOOT/ ) && (echo "console=ttyS0,115200 no_console_suspend root=/dev/ram0 r
ootwait androidboot.hardware=rpi4 androidboot.selinux=permissive buildvariant=userdebug" > out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/BOOT/cmd
line ) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/BOOTABLE_IMAGES ) && (prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/acp out/target/product
/rpi4/boot.img out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/BOOTABLE_IMAGES/ ) && (prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/acp  out/target/product/rp
i4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/BOOTABLE_IMAGES/ ) && (if [ -d "out/target/product/rpi4/system" -a "$(ls -A  out/target/product/rpi4/system)" ]; the
n mkdir -p out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/SYSTEM && prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/acp -rd out/target/product/rpi4/system/* ou
t/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/SYSTEM; fi ) && (if [ -d "out/target/product/rpi4/data" -a "$(ls -A  out/target/product/rpi4/data)
" ]; then mkdir -p out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/DATA && prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/acp -rd out/target/product/rpi4/data
/* out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/DATA; fi ) && (if [ -d "out/target/product/rpi4/vendor" -a "$(ls -A  out/target/product/rpi4/
vendor)" ]; then mkdir -p out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/VENDOR && prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/acp -rd out/target/product/
rpi4/vendor/* out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/VENDOR; fi ) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermedi
ates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/OTA ) && (cp out/target/product/rpi4/android-info.txt out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/OTA/ )
&& (mkdir -p out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/OTA/bin ) && (cp  out/target/product/rpi4/obj/EXECUTABLES/updater_intermediates/updater
out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/OTA/bin/ ) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-
target_files-eng.jerald/META ) && (cp out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/apkcerts_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-apkcerts-eng.jerald.txt out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/a
osp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/META/apkcerts.txt ) && (cp out/soong/apexkeys.txt out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/META/apexkeys.txt
) && (echo "" > out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/META/otakeys.txt ) && (cp out/target/product/rpi4/obj/ETC/file_contexts.bin_inter
mediates/file_contexts.bin out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/META/file_contexts.bin ) && (cp out/target/product/rpi4/misc_info.txt out
/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/META/misc_info.txt ) && ((cd out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4
-target_files-eng.jerald/SYSTEM; find . -type d | sed 's,$,/,'; find . \! -type d) | cut -c 3- | sort | sed 's,^,system/,' | out/host/linux-x86/bin/fs_config -C -D out/target/product/rpi4/system -S
out/target/product/rpi4/obj/ETC/file_contexts.bin_intermediates/file_contexts.bin -R "system/" > out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/
META/filesystem_config.txt ) && ((cd out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/VENDOR; find . -type d | sed 's,$,/,'; find . \! -type d) | c
ut -c 3- | sort | sed 's,^,vendor/,' | out/host/linux-x86/bin/fs_config -C -D out/target/product/rpi4/system -S out/target/product/rpi4/obj/ETC/file_contexts.bin_intermediates/file_contexts.bin -R "
vendor/" > out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/META/vendor_filesystem_config.txt ) && ((cd out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target
*files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/ROOT; find . -type d | sed 's,$,/,'; find . \! -type d) | cut -c 3- | sort | sed 's,^,,' | out/host/linux-x86/bin/fs_config -C -D out/target/p
roduct/rpi4/system -S out/target/product/rpi4/obj/ETC/file_contexts.bin_intermediates/file_contexts.bin -R "" > out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_fil
es-eng.jerald/META/root_filesystem_config.txt ) && ((cd out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/BOOT/RAMDISK; find . -type d | sed 's,$,/,'
; find . \! -type d) | cut -c 3- | sort | sed 's,^,,' | out/host/linux-x86/bin/fs_config -C -D out/target/product/rpi4/system -S out/target/product/rpi4/obj/ETC/file_contexts.bin_intermediates/file*
contexts.bin -R "" > out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/META/boot_filesystem_config.txt ) && (cp out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGIN
G/check_vintf_all_intermediates/kernel_configs.txt out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/META/kernel_configs.txt ) && (cp out/target/produ
ct/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/kernel_version.txt out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/META/kernel_version.txt ) &&
(rm -rf out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/META/dynamic_partitions_info.txt ) && (PATH=out/host/linux-x86/bin/:system/extras/ext4_utils
/:$PATH MKBOOTIMG=out/host/linux-x86/bin/mkbootimg         out/host/linux-x86/bin/add_img_to_target_files -a -v -p out/host/linux-x86 out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates
/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald ) && (find out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/META | sort >out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/tar
get_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald.zip.list ) && (find out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald -path out/target/produ
ct/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald/META -prune -o -print | sort >>out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_fil
es-eng.jerald.zip.list ) && (out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_zip -d -o out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald.zip -C out/target/product/rpi4/o
bj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald -r out/target/product/rpi4/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/aosp_rpi4-target_files-eng.jerald.zip.list )"
**acp: missing destination file
19:54:32 ninja failed with: exit status 1**

I can able to built Android 13 AOSP, generate the image and able to flash in Raspberry Pi 4. Now I am trying to generate ota package. For that I did **make -j8 dist DIST_DIR=dist_output**. I am getting the above error. I also did **make -j8 dist**. Still same error happening. Any help would be appreciated.